# Finding Intersection of two list in O(n) java8 stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, time-complexity, intersection

I have two lists, Resources and TableResources. I want to find the intersection of the two lists based on a condition i.e  subscriberId+"_"+tableName for the both the list is same. I am able to achieve this in O(N^2) time. I want to do the same using Java8 stream in O(N) time.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;

public class intersectionStream {
    private static class Resource {
        String subscriberId;
        String tableName;
        List<String> buyers;

        public Resource(String subscriberId, String tableName) {
            this.subscriberId = subscriberId;
            this.tableName = tableName;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "TableResource{" +
                    "subscriberId='" + subscriberId + '\'' +
                    ", tableName='" + tableName + '\'' +
                    ", buyers=" + buyers +
                    '}';
        }

        public String getResourceString() {
            return this.subscriberId + "_" + this.tableName;
        }

    }

    private static class TableResource {
        String subscriberId;
        String tableName;

        public TableResource(String subscriberId, String tableName) {
            this.subscriberId = subscriberId;
            this.tableName = tableName;
        }

        public String getTableResource() {
            return this.subscriberId + "_" + this.tableName;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "GlobalTableResource{" +
                    "subscriberId='" + subscriberId + '\'' +
                    ", tableName='" + tableName + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Resource> resources = new ArrayList<>();
        List<TableResource> tableResources = new ArrayList<>();
        HashSet<String> commonResources = new HashSet<>();

        resources.add(new Resource("1", "table1"));
        resources.add(new Resource("2", "table2"));
        resources.add(new Resource("3", "table3"));
        resources.add(new Resource("3", "table4"));
        resources.add(new Resource("3", "table5"));


        tableResources.add(new TableResource("2", "table2"));
        tableResources.add(new TableResource("3", "table3"));
        tableResources.add(new TableResource("5", "table5"));
        tableResources.add(new TableResource("6", "table6"));

        for(Resource resource : resources) {
            for(TableResource tableResource : tableResources) {
                if(tableResource.getTableResource().equals(resource.getResourceString())) {
                    commonResources.add(tableResource.getTableResource());
                }
            }

        }

        System.out.println("Hashset is : " + commonResources);
    }
}
```

Desired output is : Hashset is : [2_table2, 3_table3]

Comment: 1) collect the strings of one list into a set 2) iterate over the other list and add its strings to the result set if the set from step 1 also contains it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try as below,

```
Set<String> tableResourcesSet = tableResources.stream()
                .map(TableResource::getTableResource)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());

resources.stream()
        .map(Resource::getResourceString)
        .filter(tableResourcesSet::contains)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Set<String> resourceStrings = resources.stream()
                                       .map(Resource::getResourceString)
                                       .collect(toCollection(HashSet::new));

Set<String> commonResources = tableResources.stream()
                                            .map(TableResource::getTableResource)
                                            .filter(resourceStrings::contains)
                                            .collect(toSet());
```

---

Explanation:

Collecting into a HashSet takes linear time `O(n)`, while  `HashSet::contains` takes constant `O(1)` time.
So once you have a `HashSet`, you can simply iterate over the second collection in `O(n)` time.
Overall complexity os `O(n + n)` or `O(2n)`. The constant factors are *suppressed* by big `O` notation. Thus the resulting complexity is considered `O(n)`.